# I need to use a Wilcox Sign Rank test with unequal sample sizes

Tags: r, nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I'm analyzing a before and after treatment of farm fields based on runoff from rainfall events. Over 6 different farm fields there were 136 water samples from before the treatment was installed and 168 after the installation. This is obviously a paired statistical test, but while using R I need to have equal observations to complete the test. Is there a way around this?

I am looking at total dissolved solids, nitrogen and phosphorous (as both mg/L and lbs/ac). The distribution of all variables is INCREDIBLY non normal (p<2.2e-16) so I have to use Wilcox tests as opposed to an tests requiring normality. If I tried transformation, only about half of my variables are normal so I can't do that.

Comment: You cannot pair "after"s to "before"s that don't exist, that is not an R issue, that's a basic logic issue.  How did you gain 32 fields during the course of the experiment? What do you mean by "six fields that I am using"?  Also, a paired t-test assumes that the **differences** are normal, not that the underlying values are.

Comment: Sorry. 6 FARM fields. I didn't think of that. What I mean by before and after is there were 136 events before the installation of the treatment and since then there have been 168 events.

Answer (score 1):

The pairing, it seems to me, is on the farm fields. You should then have 6 "before" and 6 "after". Each field will have some number of events before and after and a paired t-test (or Wilcox test) will compare them. The t-test would assume that the differences between before and after are normally distributed.

But you have N = 6, so, unless the differences are really bizarrely distributed, no test of normality will say they are non-normal. You have to use your eyes.

But what are all the variables?

Comment: That makes sense. However, I'm looking at water collected from agricultural runnoff after rainfall events (total suspended solids, nitrogen, and phosphorous) and that still leaves the problem the numbers of before and after on each fields will still be uneven. Also using the Shaprio.test in R all three dependent variables returned a p value of  2.2e-16.

Comment: OK, first, please update your question with that information.  Tell us, as completely but simply as you can. Second, although I am still not completely sure what you need, it seems unlikely to be anything as simple as a paired t test or a Wilcox test.

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of. Someone suggested a Kruskal-Wallis test but I am hesitant to use it for fear of loosing power.

Comment: It's not so much losing power as simply doing the wrong test.  You probably need a nonlinear multilevel model.

Comment: Why would you suggest nonlinear multilevel models? Is it because of the replication from the 6 fields?

Comment: Well, for one thing, yes, you have replication. And your DV seems to be a count. And you have these "events" to account for.